# How to access active directory with perl

Tags: html, perl, active-directory, outlook

I have never done anything like this... So here it goes.

I need to be able to submit (at one time) roughly 300 user ids and get back their name and email address... The company has all this info in active directory.

Does anyone have any idea how this would work with Perl, or really any language? I don't even know what type of UI I would need, and how to actually connect to AD to get the requested information..

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need to research either LDAP or PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

you can connect to Microsoft AD with [Net::LDAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod) - Lightweight Directory Access Protocol